# Titles cut off on deleted answers page

Tags: bug, design, deleted-answers, responsive-design

On the page `https://site.stackexchange.com/users/deleted-answers/current`, the titles of the questions that go with my deleted answers are cut off, probably because I'm on a phone and there's no scroll:

[image: why didn't judge Hoffman allow Ju?????? Ramsey Clark]

The full title is "Why didn't Judge Hoffman allow Jury to sit before witness Ramsey Clark?"

Note that the full text of my (shortish) answer is there no problem.

(Didn't check the deleted Q page to see if it also has this problem as I don't know where I'd have a deleted question with a long enough title.)